# Делаю калькулятор, и хочу сделать выбор действий

Tags: c#, калькулятор

Хочу сделать калькулятор, но сложность заключается в том что я хочу сделать выбор действия.

```
Console.WriteLine("Выберите действие + - / *");
string deyst = Console.ReadLine();
```

Проблема в самом выборе, а обчисление есть.

Comment: а в чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: В том чтобы пользователь вводил например +, и выполнялось додавание, вводил -, и так далее. Чтобы вводил имеено символ действия

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы прочитать один символ из консоли, надо писать так:

```
char deyst = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

А потом через `switch` или при помощи ветвлений `if() else` делайте дальше калькулятор :)

Например:

```
char deyst = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
if(deyst == '+')
    //Выполнить сложение
else if(deyst == '-')
    //Выполнить вычитание и т.д.
```

Или же вместо `char` можете так же использовать `string`, и сравнивать уже как строки.

Например:

```
string deyst = Console.ReadLine();
if(deyst == "+")
    //Выполнить сложение
else if(deyst == "-")
    //Выполнить вычитание и т.д.
```

Comment: Большое спасибо :)